# pip - Get the latest development build from artifactory?

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

For dev builds, a SNAPSHOT release is getting published to Artifactory.  The numbers in the path below [1,2,3] are the **Jenkins build numbers**, because multiple SNAPSHOTS will be published for every dev build.

```
.
└── my-app-snapshots
    └── 2.5-SNAPSHOT
        ├── 1
        │   └── my-app-2.5-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
        ├── 2
        │   └── my-app-2.5-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
        └── 3
            └── my-app-2.5-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
```

My requirements.txt file looks like

```
my-app==2.5-SNAPSHOT
```

When I run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It always takes the artifact from build 1:

```
repo/1/my-app-2.5-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
```

How can I take the latest artifact in this case (3) based on build number?